# Network Navigator - How to reset node selections between multiple charts?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a dashboard with multiple network navigator charts that are layered on top of each other, which are shown or hidden based on bookmark selections. For example's sake, let's say I have three charts, one that shows continents, another that shows countries, and another that shows states/provinces. The idea is that you could flip from the continents view to country view to see more granular connections and so on, and then pull back out as needed.

The problem I'm seeing, however, is when you click a node in one chart and then change view to another chart, there is no easy way to reset your view without going back to the first chart and de-selecting that node. A user-case would look something like the following:

1. User clicks on "Europe" node in "Continents"
2. User switches to "Countries" view
3. In "Countries" view, it shows only nodes for European countries
4. User now wants to reset "Countries" view so that not only European nodes are displayed
5. User must flip back to "Continents" view, un-click the European node, and then return to "Countries" view

So my question is: Is there a way to reset node selections across all charts on a page so that they can avoid Step 5 in the example above?

Comment: Yes, you can do so by creating a Bookmark. Select all the desired visuals and ensure they are in the state you want them to be. Then in the Bookmark setting, set it to `Selected Visuals` and `Data`, then `Update`. Finally, add button that calls the bookmark.